# Create a number for each different field of a table

Tags: c#, for-loop, numbers, field, each

Suppose I have a table of cars.
I have brand column, and the column model.
Marks can be repeated.
And what I do is a query that shows me the mark in one column, another column in the model, and in another column generate a number for each car brand, which has to move up.
In the following example show how should be the result of my query.

```
Brand           Model                   Brand Number           

--------------- ----------------------- --------------------- 

Ford            Ranger                  1   

Ford            F100                    1         

Ford            Explorer                1

Chevrolet       Silverado               2           

Chevrolet       LUV                     2       

Mitsubishi      L200                    3        

Toyota          Hilux                   4
```

Could someone tell me how to generate that number for each mark in my query?

Comment: You would have to have absolutely everything in that for loop. Is that ok???

Comment: Sorry i don't understand

Comment: You would need to write all of the stuff into the for loop and it would need to be done using php

Comment: Add that as one of your tags otherwise people won't know as for example I haven't got a clue with c#

Answer (score 0):

If there's a many-to-one relationship between `Model` and `Make` then they should be in separate tables.  Something like this:

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | Ford
2  | Chevrolet
3  | Mitsubishi
4  | Toyota

ID | MakeID | Name
-------------------
1  | 1      | Ranger
2  | 1      | F100
3  | 1      | Explorer
4  | 2      | Silverado
5  | 2      | LUV
6  | 3      | L200
7  | 4      | Hilux
```

Then your query would be a simple `SELECT` statement which joins the two tables:

```
SELECT
    Make.Name AS Brand,
    Model.Name AS Model,
    Make.ID AS Number
FROM
    Make
    INNER JOIN Model
        ON Make.ID = Model.MakeID
```

Comment: actually my table is not about brands, I put it as an example to make myself understood, I can not change the structure of the tables, working in a clinic and I need to send these queries to prepaid medicine companies so they billed. actually, in my table are patients who may appear more than once in the table, and I need to generate a number for each of them.

Comment: @martin.softpro: This may be easier to do in application code than in a SQL query then.  Can you specify some application code in the question.  In general, as you're looping through the records (ordered by `Make`, or `Patient`) you can increment an integer each time that value changes.  (So you'd have to track the previous value across iterations of the loop.)  However, that number will _not_ be associated with that record, it would be dynamically generated by code and *not guaranteed* to be the same each time.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway, I thought it could be done with the clause over, and partition